# Have my own class behave like numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, class, numpy, operator-overloading, overriding

I had a class for my project and wants to some other methods be able accept it as parameter. What I'm trying to do is to pack the data (`numpy.ndarray` object) and some important info on the data into one object, so I don't have to store them separately and cause possible confusion in the future. However I also want this class to behave like a `numpy.ndarray` as much as possible. I overrode the operators such as +, -, etc. But for functions other than the operators (e.g. `min()`, `matplotlib.pylab.plot()`, etc) there doesn't seem to be a good way to do so.

My class is:

```
import numpy
class MyCls(object):
  def __init__(self):
    # Pack data and info into one place
    self.data = numpy.ones((10, 10))
    self.info = 'some info on the data'
```

I'd like to make it acceptable by some other functions. E.g.

```
mycls = MyCls()
x = min(mycls) # I was hoping this could return min(mycls.data)
```

or

```
from matplotlib import pylab
pylab.plot(x) # I was hoping this could plot x.data
```

I tried to override `__getitem__()`  of `MyCls`:

```
def __getitem__(self, k):
  return self.data[k]
```

It works for `min()`. I guess it's because in `min()`, it calls `__getitem__()` and each element in self.data is returned. But it won't work for another function which doesn't calls `__getitem__()`, like `pylab.plot()`.

I was wondering is it possible that for a general use of `x`, it would use `x.data`, instead of `x` itself? Or is there another good way to do the same thing?

Comment: Did you consider subclassing `numpy.ndarray`?

Comment: @JanneKarila Yes I've also considered that. But if subclassing there would be awfully lot of methods and attributes from the ndarray class...

Comment: How could it "behave like a numpy.ndarray as much as possible" if it didn't have all the methods and attributes?

Comment: Note, however, that [subclassing ndarray has some complications](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html).

Comment: @JanneKarila Yes you have a very good point. I think what I would like to do is to keep the object as simple as possible, while making calling a function with this object as parameter looks like I'm calling a function with a ndarray as parameter. Now that I see your point, I come to think this might not be a good idea. I think I'll consider subclassing ndarray. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can define `__array__` (and possibly also `__array_priority__`)...